# the Infinite sum of a sequence of function can be considered as a function itself?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_1$,$f_2$, $...$ be a sequence of non-negative measurable functions on a measure space $(X,\nu)$. Suppose that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_X {f_n}(x) d\nu \lt \infty $$

Prove that this implies

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {f_n}(x) \lt \infty $$

Now, I've tried to solve the problem by applying the monotone convergence theorem to the sequence of function (which, as defined, is increasing):

$$g_N := \sum_{n=1}^N f_n$$

I got

$$\int\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n d\nu =\int\lim_{n \to \infty}g_N d\nu= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int\sum_{n=1}^N f_nd\nu  = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N\int f_nd\nu \lt \infty $$

Now my question is: I have already proved that if $\int fd\nu \lt \infty \implies f \lt \infty $ $ \nu-
a.e$. Can I use this argument to say that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n \lt \infty$? 
Does this mean that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ can be considered as a function?

Sorry if the question seems to be stupid, but I have a contradiction on my Homework corrections and I'm not sure about this fact anymore.

Comment: $\int f\,d\nu < \infty$ implies $f < \infty$ only _almost everywhere_. But that indeed suffices to conclude $\sum f_n < \infty$ almost everywhere here.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I've forgotten to write it. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ can be considered as a function?

Yes, $g=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ is a function, defined on $X$ by $g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ for every $x$ in $X$.

In general, for every nonnegative functions $f_n$, this defines $g:X\to\overline{\mathbb R_+}=[0,+\infty]$.